# Python - Multiple replace combos in list of items

Tags: python

I have a list of tags:

```
list1 = ['tag1', tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4', 'tag5']
```

and a dictionary containing replace combos like:

```
replace_dict = {'tag2':'tag1', 'tag4':'tag3'}
```

And I need to replace each item in list 1 (key in replace_dict) with values in replace_dict, so list1 would become:

```
['tag1', 'tag1', 'tag3', 'tag3', 'tag5']
```

Comment: `[replace_dict.get(l1, l1) for l1 in list1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this:

```
print [replace_dict.get(i,i) for i in list1 ]
```

Output:

```
['tag1', 'tag1', 'tag3', 'tag3', 'tag5']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def replace(lst, dct):
    return map(lambda l: dct.get(l, l), lst)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list1 = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4', 'tag5']
    replace_dict = {'tag2':'tag1', 'tag4':'tag3'}

    print(replace(list1, replace_dict))
```

Answer (score -1):

One more approach,

```
[ replace_dict[v] if v in replace_dict.keys() else v for v in l  ]
```

Comment: This answer can be improved by removing the unneeded ``.keys()`` and the unused ``enumerate``.  Even then, the ``dict.get(k, k)`` approach is better.